# Visual Studio: "No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to debug a dll that I inject into another process.

This is my code:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "jvmti/jni.h"

bool started = false;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    std::cout << "Started?" << std::endl;

    if(ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        std::cout << "Attached to process!" << std::endl;

        if(!started)
        {
            started = true;
            void startClient();
            std::thread startThread(startClient);
        }
    } 
    else if(ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        std::cout << "Detached from process!" << std::endl;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

typedef jint(CALLBACK* GetJvmsFunc)(JavaVM**, jsize, jsize*);

void startClient()
{
    HMODULE javaHandle = GetModuleHandle(L"jvm.dll");
    GetJvmsFunc getJvmsFunc = reinterpret_cast<GetJvmsFunc>(GetProcAddress(javaHandle, "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs"));

    JavaVM** vmBuf = NULL;
    jsize* numberOfVms = NULL;
    jsize bufLen = 1;

    long* numOfVms = static_cast<long*>(numberOfVms);
    jint funcStatus = getJvmsFunc(vmBuf, bufLen, numberOfVms);

    printf("Function status: %ld\n", funcStatus);
    printf("Number of VMS: %p\n", (void*)numberOfVms);
}
```

Now whenever I run this code the process I inject into crashes. To diagnose this I have put a breakpoint at the first line of the method being called like this:
[image: The breakpoint error]

Now I don't see how this code would not be hit? I start a thread which should immediately call the `startClient()` function.

I've also tried to clean and rebuild my project, delete all the symbol files, clear my symbol cache and so on.

The only idea that I currently have is the output that visual studio produces when I debug. It doesn't explicitly state that it loads symbols for my DLL. Here is the output:

```
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Programming\VisualProjects\Incognito Premium\Incognito Premium\x64\Debug\Incognito Premium.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Incognito Premium.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x20b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x21dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2098 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What's causing this issue?

Comment: What does this line up in your if-statement do? `void startClient();`? Do you get any warnings with this code?

Comment: Are you certain that you have symbol files for the code, and that they match the build you are trying to debug? Also, are you running an optimized build under the debugger? This can often mess up the ability to set breakpoints because of code-reordering, especially with variable declarations.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's simply a forward declaration of the function so I can call it from the DLLMain. And there are no errors or warnings in this file at all.

Comment: @CodyGray Well. I would like to think so. I have checked everything. How do I check if I am running an optimized build? I have added the output that visual studio produces when I debug the application. Might be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried other lines in `StartClient` function? Do they all reject breakpoints?

Comment: @AnT Yup. http://i.imgur.com/yIEmvdf.png

Comment: Does breakpoints in DllMain work?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes they work just fine.

Comment: Surely you are debugging the wrong process.  You have to attach the debugger to the one you are, erm, attacking.

Comment: @HansPassant Im making a cheat for a game, so Im not doing anything "illegal". Anyway, I have 2 projects in my solution. One of them is the DLL and the other one is an exe. The exe loads the dll into another process. Now like 3 days ago I didn't have to do anything special. If I put a breakpoint in the dll it would automatically get triggered. But now it doesn't work. And I've tried attaching the debugger to the game and I get the exactly same error.